# SQL join to get records that do not fall between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
discount table:
id
name
description
amount

discount_exception
id
from_date
to_date
discount_id (foreign key to discount table)
```

The discount exception table is used to store date ranges where the discount SHOULD NOT be available to the user and therefore should not be displayed.  Note that there is a 1:M relationship between discount and discount_exception.  In other words, one discount can have many exceptions.

Right now, the way I have written the SQL is to grab all discounts, then loop through them in an array, and query the discount_exception table to find out if each discount falls within a particular date range.  I would prefer to modify the SQL so that one database call can grab all the discounts that do not have exception dates which fall within a specified date range.

For example, if a user is purchasing a 5 day service that runs between 2013-5-1 and 2013-5-5, I would like to check the discount and discount_exception table to find out which discounts have exceptions that fall within 2013-5-1 and 2013-5-5, and then only display those discounts that DO NOT have exceptions within the specified date range.  Is there a way to do this with one select statement instead of breaking up the SQL to make a separate call to the database for each discount?  I am having a hard time getting my head around the SQL, especially when there is a 1:M relationship between the discount table and the discount_exception table.

I was trying something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT * FROM discount INNER JOIN `discount_exceptions` ON discount.id = discount_exceptions.discount_id AND (discount_exceptions.date_from NOT BETWEEN '2013-5-1' AND '2013-5-5' OR discount_exception.date_to NOT BETWEEN '2013-5-1' AND '2013-5-5');
```

But this and other variations of this does not seem to be working.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm too tired to write out a full solution (sorry), but you'd do it by querying `discount_exception` first, then doing a LEFT INNER JOIN on the `discount` table, not the other way around as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about give this a try:

```
select * 
   from discount
    where id not in (
        SELECT discount.id FROM discount

             LEFT JOIN discount_exception 
                  ON discount.id = discount_exception.discount_id 
         WHERE ('2013-5-1'  between discount_exception.from_date and discount_exception.to_date ) 
                    OR ('2013-5-5'  BETWEEN discount_exception.from_date  and discount_exception.to_date )
                    OR (discount_exception.from_date between '2013-5-1' and '2013-5-5' )
                    OR (discount_exception.to_date between '2013-5-1' and '2013-5-5') )
 )
```

Probably better to add distinct to get distinct ID

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite work because of the 1:M relationship between discount table and discount_exceptions table.  So if there are two records in the discount_exception table that link to a discount, if one of the exception records falls inside that date while the second one doesn't, the SQL call will still return a record for the second exception.  Problem is, I don't want any discounts to be returned if there is at least one exception date that falls within the specified date ranges.

Comment: Update my answer, double check.

Comment: This will fail if `from_date, to_date` is a range inside of `'2013-05-01', '2013-05-05'`, e.g. if `from_date = '2013-05-02' and to_date = '2013-05-04'`

Comment: Good testing, correct it again, I think this cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to find all discounts applicable for the date range '2013-03-01' to '2013-03-03', firstly find all discount_exceptions that applies for this range

```
select e.*
from discount_exception e 
where e.from_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04'
or e.to_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04';
```

Joining above with discount table will give you the discount ids of all discount exceptions applicable for this date range. Distinct keyword is used so you don't get duplicate ids. Let's call this the "exception set"

```
select distinct d.id
from discount_exception e 
join discount d on d.id = e.discount_id
where e.from_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04'
or e.to_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04';
```

You can then perform another join of the discount table to find all discounts applicable for the date range (that is discounts which id isn't on the exception set above)

```
select *
from discount
where id not in (
  select distinct d.id
  from discount_exception e 
  join discount d on d.id = e.discount_id
  where e.from_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04'
  or e.to_date between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-04'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for an intersection you simply need to see whether the start of either range is within the other range.  Then you form a subquery to exclude those that match.

```
set @start_date = CAST('2013-05-01' as date);
set @stop_date = CAST('2013-05-05' as date);

select *
from discounts
where id not in (select discount_id
                 from discount_exception
                 where from_date between @start_date and @stop_date or
                       @start_date between from_date and to_date)
```